# Access an object's values using a variable

Tags: javascript

```
function sort_days() {
    var day_of_week = new Date().getDay();
    var list = ["sunday","monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday"];
    var sorted_list = list.slice(day_of_week).concat(list.slice(0,day_of_week));
    return sorted_list;
}

var newVal = {"vendor_d":"3","delivery_possible":1,"monday":0,"monday_opening_closing":0,"tuesday":1,"tuesday_opening_closing":"10:13 - 14:30","wednesday":1,"wednesday_opening_closing":"09:30 - 12:01 & 13:01 - 17:10","thursday":1,"thursday_opening_closing":"09:40 - 12:10 & 13:10 - 18:18","friday":0,"friday_opening_closing":0,"saturday":1,"saturday_opening_closing":"05:06 - 13:15 & 14:10 - 20:12","sunday":1,"sunday_opening_closing":"06:20 - 14:15 & 15:15 - 22:20"}
var days = sort_days();

for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  console.log(days[i]);
  console.log ( newVal.days[i] ); // here I wanna get newVal.monday value
};
```

here I want to get the `newVal.days[i]` value . I am not too sure I am doing it correctly . but when i am putting `newVal.monday` its giving me correct value .

Comment: ....... `newVal[days[i]]`? There is no json here.

Comment: see my edit ... You cant down vote without clearifying

Comment: @AshishNautiyal: Yea, you can. People _can_ vote however they want. I'm not saying they _should_, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newVal` doesn't have a `days` property, which is what you're trying to access. You mean to say:

```
 console.log ( newVal[ days[i] ] );
```

Comment: Thanks it worked . Instead  of down voting like these Ninjas you answered. Thanks